# Analytical Geometry:- Circles tricky question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, inequality

If two distinct chords of the circle $x^2+y^2-ax-by=0$ drawn from $(a,b)$ are divided by the $x$ axis in the ratio 2:1, prove that $a^2>3b^2$.

Comment: What "is divided by the $\;x-$ axis..." ? Aren't you talking of **two** cords from the same point on the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\left(p,q\right)$ be the other end of the chord. Then a point that divides the chord in the ratio $2:1$ is given by $\left(\dfrac{2p+a}3,\dfrac{2q+b}3\right)$. If this lies on the $x$-axis then $2q+b=0$ or $q=-\dfrac b2$.

Recalling that $\left(p,q\right)$ lies on the given circle, we can write: $p^2+\left(-\dfrac b2\right)^2-ap-b\left(-\dfrac b2\right)=0$ which is quadratic in $p$ viz.: $p^2-ap+\dfrac34b^2=0$ or $p = \dfrac12(a+ or-(a^2-3b^2)^{1/2})$ from which for real $p$ with two distinct solutions we must have $a^2>3b^2$.